# Eclipse doesn't see the PySide classes

Tags: python, eclipse, pyside, pydev

I have a trouble with PySide/PyDev/Eclipse

I typed this code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

app=QApplication(sys.argv)

web=QWebView()
web.load(QUrl('http://google.com'))
web.show()
```

[image]

Eclipse shows red crosses on the side, and says QApplication and QWebView and so on, are `undefined varibales.` The problem is that program compiles without errors and gives me right result. 
I checked PYTHONPATH and it shows PySide folder over there. 
Don't know what to do, obviously I can write programs with this issue, but it's just annoying =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding PySide to your [Forced Builtins](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins) should solve that problem.

Comment: I added it to my forced builtins but I still have the same problem!  It runs fine though.

Comment: I did the same, but had to restart Eclipse. Then it worked fine.